# Is the view n times field updated at every refresh, or at every new visitor?

Tags: discussion

If I refresh the page of a question, or come back during the same browsing session, is the time views counter increased anyway? 
My impression is "yes", I am asking just out of curiosity

Comment: I refreshed this like 10 times and it still says "viewed 3 times". So the answer is no.

Comment: Ok, so I think what I saw is that the number of counts that you see the first time is not updated, then when you refresh it increases  with your first visit

Comment: Cba looking for proof, but I think I've read that theres a 15 minute window after which you count as another view. So if you refreshed 6 times now it wouldn't add any views, but if you refreshed once every 20 minutes for the next 2 hours it'd add 6 views.

Comment: I remember similarly to OGHaza; there was a user asking about it on Meta.SE so they could implement a similar system on their own site.

Comment: sometimes I forget about meta.SE...  now I found some similar question  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stack-overflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question?rq=1